# Updating stock_satus for WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on frontend ajax script to add woocommerce variable product from the frontend.

I have managed to set attributes & variations successfully for a particular product.

Only problem I'm facing is that variations created under products are always out of stock/unavailable.

I'm using following line to update `_stock_status` of the variation

```
update_post_meta($variation_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
```

After running above code, In woocommerce product metabox I can see 'instock' as selected option. but value="" field remains empty as follow :

```
<select name="variable_stock_status[0]">
    <option selected="selected" value="">In stock</option>
    <option value="outofstock">Out of stock</option>                    
</select>
```

Which apparently sets product as unavailable through woocommerce `get_available_variations()` function

What I'm missing here ? What is the correct way of setting/adding variations via frontend using ajax?

**Note :** I'm using latest version of WooCommerce : 2.5.5

Comment: You might need to set the stock quantity too, use this meta to do do : `add_post_meta( $variation_id, '_stock', 10, true );`